# FFMPEG merge two videos which don't have any audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I created two different videos which are created by combining multiple images into videos. Below is the command for that.

```
"-f","concat","-safe", "0","-i",path,"-vsync","vfr","-pix_fmt","yuv420p",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path+"/output1.mp4"
```

Here path is the input path of a text file in which I have given path of all the images that needs to be merged.

Now I am trying merge these two videos into a single video.
For this I am using the following command.

```
-i, /storage/emulated/0/output.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/output1.mp4, -filter_complex, [1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1;[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v], -map, [v], -preset, ultrafast, /storage/emulated/0/output3.mp4
```

But it doesn't work and doesn't give any error in logs. But this is the last statement that gets printed in the progress method and seems like some error to me

> Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1000x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 838 kb/s, 0.83 fps, 1 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)

This is the details of the both videos.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 279 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x854 [SAR 1:1 DAR 640:427], 279 kb/s, 0.25 fps, 0.20 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/output1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 839 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1000x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 838 kb/s, 0.83 fps, 1 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

**UPDATE**
These are the logs after using the command shared in answer.

```
Successfully opened the file.
D/ffmpeg: progress [Parsed_scale2ref_0 @ 0xf16390c0] w:iw h:ih flags:'bilinear' interl:0
D/ffmpeg: progress [Parsed_setsar_1 @ 0xf1639120] Setting 'sar' to value '1'
D/ffmpeg: progress [Parsed_concat_2 @ 0xf1639180] Setting 'n' to value '2'
D/ffmpeg: progress [Parsed_concat_2 @ 0xf1639180] Setting 'v' to value '1'
D/ffmpeg: progress [Parsed_concat_2 @ 0xf1639180] Setting 'a' to value '0'
D/ffmpeg: progress Parsing a group of options: output url /storage/emulated/0/output3.mp4.
D/ffmpeg: progress Applying option map (set input stream mapping) with argument [v].
D/ffmpeg: progress Successfully parsed a group of options.
D/ffmpeg: progress Opening an output file: /storage/emulated/0/output3.mp4.
```

Comment: Remove the last `[2:a]` in concat filter.

Comment: @Gyan it gives the following error now `:a:0' in filtergraph description [1:v:0]scale=640:480,setsar=1[1v];[0:v:0][2:a][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.`

Comment: Your 2nd video has no audio, then use `[2:a]` instead.

Comment: None of my videos have audio.I have created these videos by merging images into a video.So none of them have images

Comment: @Gyan I have updated the question. Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
-i, /storage/emulated/0/output.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/output1.mp4, 
-filter_complex, [1:v][0:v]scale2ref[ua][b];[ua]setsar=1[ua];[b][ua]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v],
-map, [v], -preset, ultrafast, /storage/emulated/0/output3.mp4
```

Comment: It doesn't give any error but doesn't complete either. No error or warning shown in logs.

Comment: As I would expect a user of your rep level and experience to know, we prefer that answers include some explanation, and not just be ''Use this command.''

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Added logs in the question

Comment: Run with `-v 48` added and share full console output.

Comment: @Gyan updated the logs in the question  with `-v 48`

Comment: Share full console output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working now. Issue was with output file not getting created by the command. I created a new file manually and then passed it to the command and it worked.